# Qualifying similarities between languages - e.g., German and Norwegian

Tags: comparative-linguistics, germanic-languages, german, norwegian

I learnt "fluent" German and Dutch and I am learning Norwegian. German is much closer to Dutch than Norwegian. Yet, there are obvious strong and fascinating similarities between German and Norwegian, which go beyond similar word stems or comparable grammar.

Explained in neophyte words as a non-linguist, I would say that in many ways, German and Norwegian have the same "philosophy" or underlying "thinking". Those expressions are extremely approximate, I would like to find a more accurate description for characterizing and understanding those similarities.

We can identify the following "levels" of likeness,

- Words

e.g., svart -> schwarz, styrke/kraft -> Stärke/Kraft, strøm -> Strom, makt -> Macht

In fact, I would say that a good 2/3 of the Norwegian words are very similar to some German equivalents, often even closer in pronunciation than in written

Some correspondances seems to occur at the subword level, it is then almost possible to guess the Norwegian word from the German one using a learnt "tranformation",

e.g., til- -> zu such as in tilbake -> zurück, tilfeldighet -> Zufall, tillegge -> hinzufügen etc., or opp -> auf such as in oppstå etc.

- Verbs formation

Similarities at different levels,

using modal verbs to form conditional tense or express obligation, will etc.,

using separable prefix to give a nuance or another meaning to the stem verb, e.g., opp|stå -> auf|stehen with stå -> stehen,

using similar tenses to similar usage, present, {preteritum, perfect, past-perfect} for the past indicative, future indicative with auxiliary, etc.

with similar irregular verbs conjugation (e.g., similar vowel in preteritum and perfekt)

- Expressions

This goes beyond just the word likeness of words, a way of saying is similar in Norwegian and German, with no such close equivalent in say, English and French.

e.g., underveis -> unterwegs (to further compare, in English we would say *on the road* and in French, *en route* or *en chemin*, with no one-word equivalent afaik),

det handler om -> es handelt sich um,

noe lys -> etwas Licht (*something light* or *quelque chose lumière* don't exist in English or French),

gi beskjed til noen -> jdm Bescheid geben (in French, the verb in equivalent expression is *mettre* (put), and not *donner* (give))

---

In fact, two third of a Norwegian text could be quoted as similar to German with respect to those "level of likeness" and probably others.

How would you characterize those linguistic similarities? What does classical comparative linguistic (e.g., of German and Norwegian) says?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons why German and Norwegian seem similar. One is that they come from the same language spoken a few thousands of years ago. The second is that German had a more modern influence (due to the Hanseatic League). Actually, there are two versions of that influence, the other being indirect influence (German influenced Danish, which influenced Norwegian). A third possibility to consider is that both German and Norwegian could be influenced by a third language (French, or English though that's easier to identify nowadays).

The best way to determine if some property is a shared retention from Proto-Germanic is to look at ancient texts (Old English, Old Saxon, Old High German, Old Norse, Gothic). Taking the example of "black", the word is from [Proto-Germanic *swartaz*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/swartaz), itself said to derive from Indo-European *swordo*. In the case of *tilbake* and *zurück*, this is what is known as a "calque", a borrowed translation. This is a more recent lexical development, and one would have to undertake a careful textual study to see when it was first attested in Scandinavian or West Germanic.